# Immutable List and Typescript proper way to define an array of objects with type

Tags: typescript, immutable.js, immutablelist

Here is my JSON data which i get from the server

```
[
  {
    "property1": 1,
    "property2": "asd",
    "property3": 2
  },
  {
    "property1": 1,
    "property2": "asd",
    "property3": 2
  },
  {
    "property1": 1,
    "property2": "asd",
    "property3": 2
  }

]
```

I want to define Immutable List object which uses this `interface`

```
export interface myObject {
    propert1: number,
    propert2: string,
    propert3: number
}
```

I tried something like this but its not working :

```
private myObjectList: Immutable.List<myObject> = Immutable.List([]);
```

and then using `angular $http`

```
$http.get('my url to the json').then(function(data){
   this.myObjectList = data.data;
});
```

But then `myObjectList variable` is exactly the same as the json, instead I want to keep the Immutable List Object and somehow push the data in it with my specific Type.
In other words if the JSON objects are not exactly as the `interface` `myObject`, it should return an error

I also Tried this but then i get typescript error

```
$http.get('my url to the json').then(function(data){
   this.myObjectList = Immutable.List(data.data);
});

error: Type 'List<{}>' is not assignable to type 'List<Queries>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first attempt doesn't assign an immutable list, it assigns the exact data to `myObjectList`.

Your second attempt is correct, the error you are getting is because the compiler can't infer the response type.
Try:

```
$http.get('my url to the json').then(function(data){
   this.myObjectList = Immutable.List(data.data as Queries);
});
```

Comment: nice now it works but with angular in my html when i try to display the rows  via ng-repeat is this the proper way of doing it

`ng-repeat="object in myObjectList._tail.array` because if i remove tail and array the ng-repeat does not work

Comment: I'm not an angular develop so I don't know.  If you can't find answers to that problem then post a new question about it