# Replacing issues in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I have below json objects in my angular 4 project.

```
  NationalityList: any[]; Nationality: any = {};
```

Inside both json objects having a property named "Nation". NationalityList holding multiple Nation lists. Nationality is using to bind model in Entry fields. When I edit a Nation from NationalityList; I am copying value to "Nationality" and showing in textbox. When Iam typing in text box its effecting in both NationalityList and Nationality. How to prevent this?

```
GetNationalities() {
  this.loading = true;
  var param = {};
  this.JsonApiService.CommonService('HCP/GetAllNationalityList', this.JsonApiService.encrypt(JSON.stringify(param)).toString()).subscribe((Resp) => {
    this.NationalityList = this.JsonApiService.decrypt(Resp);
    this.loading = false;
    this.DestroyDataTable();
  });
}

SaveNationality(f: NgForm) {
if (!f.valid) {
  this.InitializeAllValidation(f)
  return;
}
this.Nationality.Mode = 'ADD';
this.JsonApiService.CommonService('HCP/SaveNationality', this.JsonApiService.encrypt(JSON.stringify(this.Nationality)).toString()).subscribe((Resp) => {
  var Response = this.JsonApiService.decrypt(Resp);
  if (Response.Status == true) {
    this.toastr.success('Nationality has been added successfully', '');
    this.GetNationalities();
    this.Cancel();
    this.DestroyAllValidation(f);
  }
  else {
    if (Response.ResultMsg.length > 0)
      this.toastr.error(Response.ResultMsg, '');
    else
      this.toastr.error('Unable to save Nationality', '');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: share some code

Comment: @rijin code added

Comment: Its happening because by default its mutable. Try to have it as immutable obj

Comment: @Shashank Vivek How to make it immutable?

Comment: I hope this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41238306/immutable-list-and-typescript-proper-way-to-define-an-array-of-objects-with-type

Comment: above link not fixed my issue

Comment: Objects are mutable and passed by reference, use `Object.assign`.